# Unknown error: Runtime.evaluate while executing Javascript in seleniumChromeDriver

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to execute Javascript in python's selenium Chromedriver. I have already tried researching the unknown error as suggested in this link [nknown error: Runtime.evaluate threw exception: SyntaxError: Unexpected token var](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28452332/nknown-error-runtime-evaluate-threw-exception-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-va/28452957), in which the accepted solution involved properly formatting the js, which didn't work in my case

My script looks like:

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data:  {
        "code": "a=input(\"\");\nprintf(\"Part A\\n\");\nSA=6*a^2;\nprintf(\"SA = %d\\n\",SA);\nr1=(6*a^2/(4*pi))^(1/2);\nprintf(\"Radius = %.2f\\n\",r1);\nprintf(\"Part B\\n\");\nv=a^3;\nr2=(3*v/(4*pi))^(1/3);\nprintf(\"Radius = %.2f\\n\",r2);\n",
        "input": "",
    },
    url: "code.evaluate.abc.php",
    dataType: "json",
    });
```

Since it is not possible to type this as a string into driver.execute_script(javascript_string), the newlines were removed to produce this one line:

```
$.ajax({type: "POST",data:  {"code": "a=input(\"\");\nprintf(\"Part A\\n\");\nSA=6*a^2;\nprintf(\"SA = %d\\n\",SA);\nr1=(6*a^2/(4*pi))^(1/2);\nprintf(\"Radius = %.2f\\n\",r1);\nprintf(\"Part B\\n\");\nv=a^3;\nr2=(3*v/(4*pi))^(1/3);\nprintf(\"Radius = %.2f\\n\",r2);\n","input": "",},url: "code.evaluate.abc.php",dataType: "json"});
```

This one-liner is correct because when copy pasted into the browser's developer options console, it works as intended, but when I execute it from inside driver.execute_script, it produces the following error:

> WebDriverException: unknown error: Runtime.evaluate threw exception: SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
>     (Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.162)
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528139 (47ead77cb35ad2a9a83248b292151462a66cd881),platform=Linux 4.13.0-37-generic x86_64)

P.S.: Console.log, alerts and small javascript commands and other webdriver commands are correctly executed.

Comment: Can you add a `return true;` at the end of the script and see if it helps

Comment: Nope it didn't help. It was a matter of python not escaping the escape sequences properly as I have mentioned in the comment to DebanjanB's answer.

Comment: Please check the answer I posted now

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned the following *JavaScript* works perfectly in the Browser's Developer Console :

```
$.ajax({type: "POST",data:  {"code": "a=input(\"\");\nprintf(\"Part A\\n\");\nSA=6*a^2;\nprintf(\"SA = %d\\n\",SA);\nr1=(6*a^2/(4*pi))^(1/2);\nprintf(\"Radius = %.2f\\n\",r1);\nprintf(\"Part B\\n\");\nv=a^3;\nr2=(3*v/(4*pi))^(1/3);\nprintf(\"Radius = %.2f\\n\",r2);\n","input": "",},url: "code.evaluate.abc.php",dataType: "json"});
```

But doesn't works through *ChromeDriver*, it seems your main issue is the **version compatibility** between the binaries you are using as follows :

- You are using *chromedriver=2.35*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.35*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.35/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v62-64**

- You are using *chrome=65.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v2.37*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.37/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v64-66**

So there is a clear mismatch between the *ChromeDriver* version (*v2.35*) and the *Chrome Browser* version (*v65.0*)

### Solution

- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to [**ChromeDriver v2.37**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version at ***Chrome v65.x*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.37 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.37/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *WebClient*.
- Execute your `@Test`.

Comment: It wasn't a compatibility issue for me. but a problem of the escape sequences: the \" actually is interpreted as " by python. If we write "code"="hi", that works alright. I also tried writing "code"="hi\" and that works right as well indicating the inverted comma isn't escaped. Also "hi\"hello" produces an error.   So can you suggest some way to integrate the json code as it is (I need the escape sequences in my code that is sent to the CodeMirror cm-s default hidden textarea), into the driver.execute_script command? Else can you suggest how to integrate the requests module with selenium.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Python's multiline string so I can use exact JavaScript in my code as well

```
driver.execute_script("""

var JS={"abc": "def"}

console.log(JSON.stringify(JS));
""")
```

This will make sure no escaping issues